# Using slice and get rid of the middle two numbers

Tags: python, list, slice

This time I want to get the following result by using slice. However, I could not manage it. Is there a negative version of List[2:4] in this scenario?

```
Input:
List=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Output:
List =[1,2,5,6,7]
```

Edited:
By negative I mean that the I want this: List =[1,2,5,6,7] instead of this: List=[3,4]. I saw the answers and they work. Thank you very much but is there way to get the result by doing slicing?

Ps: I am not able to give votes due to my low level. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: No, there is no way to do represent this with a slice

Answer (score -1):

First off `List[3:5] = [4, 5]` so the "negative" version would be `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]`. You can produce that with:

`List[:3] + List[5:]`

Comment: Thank you very much this works, but I want to do get the result by slicing in one operation.

Answer (score -1):

`List[:3] + List[5:]`

Hopefully that's not the real name of the variable

Comment: Thank you very much this works, but I want to do get the result by slicing in one operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `del` to remove part of a list specified by a slice:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  
del xs[2:4]

print(xs)
# [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works, but I want to do get the result by slicing in one operation. I cannot use del :(

Comment: @ApplicatorDeveloper Sure you can. It's been part of Python for a long time. I have yet another idea, but I feel like you'll just make up further restrictions...

Comment: @ApplicatorDeveloper It's not what you want anyway (which is impossible), just a way to do the same as `del` without using `del`. [Pumpkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Married..._with_Children_characters#Kelly_Bundy).

Comment: @KellyBundy, About the code, thank you very much for your time.  About the rest: I thought that was your real name. I love that woman btw. She was perfect both in Anchorman 1 & 2. Also, that show was great. What a coincidence, I listened this song today: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRDBvKGc1fE